# Error 255 when trying to install openssl-1.0.1g from source

Tags: compiling, install-from-source, openssl

```
installing man1/cms.1
cms.pod around line 457: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 461: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 465: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 470: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 474: Expected text after =item, not a number
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 71.
make: *** [install_docs] Error 255
```

I get this error when trying to build from source on ubuntu 14.04.

-thanks!

Answer (score 17):

from [this page](https://github.com/shadow/shadow/issues/206):

Changing

`make install`

to

`make install_sw`

(installing OpenSSL without the man pages) alleviates this issue.

Answer (score 2):

POD files found to be generated with a lot of errors from the perl 5.18 point of view. See the patch here https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/57

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How do i install the patch?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

Go to line specified in specified file (cms.pod) and change `=item 1` to `=item '1'`.

I figured this out after trying to install openssl0.9.8 for guitar pro 6.

Edit:

```
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.pod around line 109: Expected text after =item, not a number
```

If you are having the problem with openssl0.9.8 and guitar pro 6, there are a lot of files to update. If there is a away to mass edit these files O_O so much want

Comment: Hi David,

What was wrong? :D

Answer (score 1):

From: [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/source/)

"The latest stable version is the 1.0.2 series of releases. This is also our Long Term Support (LTS) version (support will be provided until 31st December 2019). The 1.0.1 version is currently only receiving security bug fixes and all support will be discontinued for this version on 31st December 2016. Our newest version is 1.1.0 which is currently in alpha testing and should not be used for production purposes at this time. The 0.9.8 and 1.0.0 versions are now out of support and should not be used."

Try using the supported version [here.](https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz)

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer at all.  I'm trying to build a version of the 1.0.2 series and I have the same problem.  Clearly it is not going to be solved simply by building a later version.