# How to install Apache with Openssl 1.0.1?

Tags: apache2, software-installation, openssl

I want to test Heartbleed on Apache Server. I removed Apache and Openssl from my OS (Ubutu 12.04). I wonder how can I install Apache WITH  the Openssl version 1.0.1 in order to be able to test this vulnerability on my own localhost (Apache Server) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can compile it yourself.

1. Download [OpenSSL 1.0.1f](http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1f.tar.gz):

   ```
   wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1f.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract `openssl-1.0.1f.tar.gz`:

   ```
   tar -xvzf openssl-1.0.1f.tar.gz
   ```
3. Enter the created directory:

   ```
   cd openssl-1.0.1f
   ```
4. Configure OpenSSL:

   ```
   ./config
   ```
5. Compile OpenSSL:

   ```
   make
   ```
6. Test if everything went right:

   ```
   make test
   ```
7. Install OpenSSL:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Now OpenSSL is installed on your PC and you can test it.

Comment: But if I install Apache Server it will use its own Openssl, or the one I install using your method ?

Comment: I'm not sure. The [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/configure.html#options) say that it'll search for an installed version of OpenSSL or you can specify the location yourself using `--with-ssl=/usr/bin` while compiling Apache2. I think that if you're using `apt-get` it'll install and use the latest OpenSSL as a dependency. So the solution would be to compile Apache2 by yourself as well.

Comment: Afterwards you should create a symlink to the new binaries `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl ``which openssl```

Comment: Just want to add that if the `make install` step fails because of some man page problem, use `make install_sw` instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/742712/257860