# dpkg -i error: unable to open ... no such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, lubuntu, dpkg

I try to install libssl 0.9.8 on lubuntu 20.04.1.

I have found no way to install it using apt, so that I downloaded a `.deb` package from [the ubuntu Trusty (14.04) launchpad archive](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libssl0.9.8/0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1).

I try to install it this way:

```
kids@Dani:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

It gives me the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 268220 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl0.9.8:amd64 (0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
```

---

I've tried to make such file make such directory and remove it, but nothing changed.
Do you know a way to install it using apt?
Any other way to fix it?

I am using the correct architecture (64-bit on 64-bit VM, using VMware workstation player on 64-bit windows 10).

Comment: Why don't you try to `apt install libssl1.1`?

Comment: Why are you trying to install an old Ubuntu 14.02 package on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package sources are available [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl098/0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1).
The package sources can be downloaded and compiled using the following syntax:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/openssl098/0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1/openssl098_0.9.8o.orig.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssl098_0.9.8o.orig.tar.gz
cd ./openssl-0.9.8o/
./config
make
make test
sudo make install_sw
```

- On the last line, the "install_sw" (instead of just "install") is a walkaround to avoid an error related to man pages. There is another way to deal with the problem; see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454575/error-255-when-trying-to-install-openssl-1-0-1g-from-source).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a different package that I managed to solve using the following sequence.
First, the error:

```
(Reading database ... 66160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot (11.0.6+10-2) over (11.0.9+11.1-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot_11.0.6+10-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/man/ja/man1/jcmd.1.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot_11.0.6+10-2_amd64.deb
```

While investigating, I noticed something weird in the folder `/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/man`:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/man
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct  1 06:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 root root 4096 Nov  4 08:42 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Aug 30 11:33 ja -> ja_JP.UTF-8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct  1 06:36 ja_JP.UTF-8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  4 08:42 man1
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  4 08:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct  1 06:36 ..
```

The folder `ja` (which seemed to be the origin of `dpkg` error) was in fact a symlink pointing to the folder `ja_JP.UTF-8`.

I solved my issue by removing the symlink and recreating it as a real folder (also recreating its child folder `man1`):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/man$ sudo rm ja
/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/man$ sudo mkdir ja
/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/man$ sudo mkdir ja/man1
```

I then reinstalled the `adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot_11.0.6+10-2` package and it went smoothly.

Comment: It looks to differ than my case. I do not have a symlink, nor creating a real foldor (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8.dpkg-new) helps